# Does having more than one of the same warlord skill increase the proc rate?

Tags: blood-brothers

Warlords can now have up to 3 skills. But what are the effect of having multiple skills that are the same?

For example, if my warlord has Triple Strike with a 30% proc rate, and I add another 2 Triple Strike skills both with 30% proc rate. Will this mean an overall 90% proc rate? or will it take the highest (i.e. 30%)? or some other formula perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the help section of the game it stats that adding multiple skills to a warlord does NOT increase the chance of a proc occuring.

http://bloodbrothersgame.wikia.com/wiki/File:Addaskill.png

Answer (score 1):

According to this [forum post](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/59207/t1824107-description-of-3-skill-warlords/),

> You can only have 1 Opener , 1 Support, 1 Attack type of skill from my
>   understanding. Even if your able of adding lets say 3 attack skill,
>   the game will only choose 1 of them 3 to fight in the battle at random
>   so it's useless to have 2 of the same skill because only 1 of them
>   will be selected at random and it will be a 30% proc. This also goes
>   for 2 buffing skills only 1 will be selected at random.

The proc rate will also stack if the skill is the same. Since you have Triple Strike 3 times, it will in fact have a 90% proc rate.

Comment: I missed that first part of the question. Disregard this until I update it.

Comment: Yeah this is actually a huge area of debate. People are publishing statistics and asking Dena but no one can confirm that having 3 of the same skill will guarantee a "Theroetical" 90% or 3 chances of 30% proc.

I want someone to confirm this so bad.